# Excel VBA link two user selected cells with hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am currently trying to link two user selected cells automatically with hyperlinks.
The user can select two different cells (one after another via inputboxes). To those two cells hyperlinks should be added which point from cell 1 to cell 2 and cell 2 to cell 1.

So far I have this:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Hyperlinks()
Dim FirstHyperlink As Range
Dim SecondHyperlink As Range

Set FirstHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select first cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 1 selection", Type:=8)
Set SecondHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select second cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 2 selection", Type:=8)

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstHyperlink.Address, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    SecondHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=FirstHyperlink.Value

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=SecondHyperlink.Address, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    FirstHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=SecondHyperlink.Value

End Sub
```

However I get a run-time error 13: Type mismatch pointing to

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstHyperlink.Address, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        SecondHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=FirstHyperlink.Value
```

Anyone an idea what causes the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix your `Anchors`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hyperlinks()
Dim FirstHyperlink As Range
Dim SecondHyperlink As Range

Set FirstHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select first cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 1 selection", Type:=8)
Set SecondHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select second cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 2 selection", Type:=8)

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    SecondHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=FirstHyperlink.Value

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=SecondHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    FirstHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=SecondHyperlink.Value

End Sub
```

*This assumes that the cells have some non-null values to begin with.*

Answer (score 1):

For completeness reasons:

Here is the code that I finally worked with. I wrote some more lines of code to make it work on different worksheets and not only on one single worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hyperlinks()
Dim FirstHyperlink As Range
Dim SecondHyperlink As Range
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet

Set FirstHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select first cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 1 selection", Type:=8)
Set FirstSheet = FirstHyperlink.Worksheet
Set SecondHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select second cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 2 selection", Type:=8)
Set SecondSheet = SecondHyperlink.Worksheet

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & SecondSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & SecondHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=FirstHyperlink.Value

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=SecondHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & FirstSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & FirstHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=SecondHyperlink.Value

End Sub
```